# possible to display some debug messages in the html code from a .cs file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following problem:

I have my view and the controller. From the controller, I access some backend classes and methods. Now I want to make the following:

I want to write a debug version of my site. In this debug version I want to show debug information which is generated in the backend classes.

The problem is, that I can not send them directly to my `.cshtml` view, or is this possible?

I need to send some text to my `.cshtml` but not from the controller itself, from some other classes and then write it e.g. to a `<div id="myDebug"></div>`

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Why don't you use a logger (for example [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)) in order to get all debug informations?

Comment: because I did not know that there is such a thing :)

Comment: You should use such tools, they are really useful, and avoid sending too many information to users that should not see them...

Comment: I was also going to mention log4net, but there's another project I have seen which has a demo for a real-time dashboard ElmahR (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/377394/ElmahR-equals-ELMAH-plus-SignalR-1-0-0-released) which uses SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I like to use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) for writing debug info.

You could use an ActionFilter then like Yuriy proposed, for example when an action on your controller is invoked:

```
public static class Logger
{
    static readonly NLog.Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SomeLogger");

    public static void LogDebug(string message)
    {
        _logger.Debug(message);
    }
}

public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{    
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //do something
        Logger.Debug("Debug info") 
    }
}
```

You could use the static Logger in your backend classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to implement own ActionFilter and depending on current mode inject debug info into ViewBag and then render it in view if presented.